# Hide the text that inside the text field

Tags: java

how to hide the text inside the text field?

I'm using the radio button and group with 2 selection(A and B).

For example, when i choose A, the text inside textfield B will hidden. When choose B, the text inside textfield A will hidden and textfield B will appear.

```
 jtfLTCurrentTransferLimit.setVisible(true);
 jtfLTCurrentWithdrawLimit.setVisible(false);
```

i using .setVisible to archive this. But the textfield will gone when i clicked.

Any solution?

Comment: Swing, AWT, SWT, JME, GWT.. Care to narrow down the GUI toolkit being used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the text of the hidden field into a `String` field and then set that hidden field's value to `""`. Then you can restore that value later when it becomes unhidden. You may also want to disable the hidden field, as suggested by the other answer, to prevent editing.

Answer (score 0):

You could `setEnabled(false)` and then set the foreground and background colour of the text to the same colour.

Comment: The only caution with this approach is the user will still be able to select the "hidden" text and copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: Actually, maybe not, since it's disabled.